# QtQuick or QtWidget

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtwidgets

I have an application in the works to display stock market graphs.

I retrieve the courses from the Internet and display them on my application, with a lot of customization, tracking available and potentially live.

I hesitate to do it with Qwidget or QtQuick.

QtQuick is well suited if the window is often resized? I move the sizes of my windows a lot.

I see on one side people say that QtQuick is more for tablet etc and QtWidget is more for pc.
And on the other hand, I've seen a lot of people saying they switch their desktop application from QtWidget to QtQuick either professionally or personally, and they often say they don't want to go back.

My project may take me some time and I would like to take the most optimized one between the two.

I code in python but I would probably translate my code in C++.
I would do the prototype in python and the final version in C++.

QtQuick is really adaptable with python? Loading data, indicators to place on the graph etc. are handled with QtQuick or externally with python/c++ ? I really have a hard time projecting myself with QtQuick even if after all I read about it, I really prefer to start with it.

Basically, I'd like to do something like [this](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/).

So, I need to be able to customize the style of my application, I need performance to display the graphs and be able to add indicators/line drawing by hand etc. with good performance.

I would start more easily by doing my project with QtWidget than if I switch to QtQuick, I need to learn the QML from the beginning.

QtQuick seems fine to me but I'm afraid of making a mistake, and I don't want to waste time doing my application with QtQuick if it's not adapted.

Answer (score 1):

**My suggestion is Qt Quick.**

Because Qt Quick is developed in 2010 after ios and android came out. In my opinion, after that Qt Community began to focus on Qt Quick more than Qt Widget. Most of guiders suggest that Qt Widget is for Desktop apps, Qt Quick is for ios, Android and embedded but you can either use both for all. After I checked your app which is in your link, as a user who used Qt widget and Qt Quick I think you will feel more comfortable yourself by using Qt Quick.

Here is some examples which are available in Qt. You can easily use them when you installed Qt from Examples. These examples are related to your project according to your reference link. Checking out the examples related to your subject will give you a better idea before beginning your project.

**Qt Quick:**

1- [Multiple Graph Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtdatavisualization-qmlmultigraph-example.html)

2- [Scene Graph Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-painteditem-example.html)

**Qt Widget:**

1- [Diagram Scene Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html)

2- [400 Chips Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html)

3- [Graphics View Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-flowlayout-example.html)

[image]

Here is also a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzyvziQf4JQ) comparing Qt Quick and Qt Widget.

**Is QtQuick adaptable with python?**

Yes, here is the [reference](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html) but Qt Widgets projects use C++.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks you, I think I'm gonna go with QQuick.